# Nakajima quiver varieties with different stability conditions related by sequence of Mukai-flops?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Conjecturally, any two symplectic resolutions are related by sequences of Mukai flops. Consider different symplectic resolutions coming from Hamiltonian reductions with different stability conditions. For example,  two Nakajima quiver varieties $\mathcal{M}_{\theta_1,\zeta}(v,w)$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\theta_2,\zeta}(v,w)$ (we fix the dimension vectors $(v,w)$, fix the parameter $\zeta$ i.e., the image of moment map) with different regular (not on a wall) stability conditions $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. I was wondering whether in this case the conjecture follows from GIT generality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Namikawa recently [proved the conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1698) you're referring to (at least for symplectic cones with a "good" $C^*$ action), by establishing that every such symplectic resolution is a Mori dream space.  For quiver varieties, I think one doesn't need to use Namikawa's results and can just think directly about variation of GIT; this won't always give flops, but it should in the context of a symplectic reduction for a flat moment map.